# What is the counterpart of an appendix?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The appendix is what is appended to something. What do we call something that is prepended to something else?

Comment: The opposite to appendix is the main-part. There is no *?prependix*. It's more like *on-*, *at-* or *off-* then *ante-*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When describing parts of a book, the "preface" or "prologue" are common.

Comment: This is correct. Except for its anatomical meaning, "appendix" refers specifically to an addition to the end of a written work, usually a book. It is not a general term for something added after something else, although it could be used that way in a metaphorical sense. So the corresponding "in front of" meaning would be what @ptomato says.

Comment: "Foreword" (not to be confused with "forward") and "Introduction" are also common.

Comment: "[Prefatory](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prefatory) material" or preliminary material would do as a more general alternative for a preface.

Answer (score 1):

Was expanding my comment to @ptomato's answer but didn't get it committed within the 5-minute mark, so am elevating this to a full answer.

In books, "foreword" (not to be confused with "forward") and "introduction" are also common. *However*:

In "appendix", the "ap-" seems to just convey "on" or "with"; it's the "pend" that conveys "hanging", thus "downward" or "following". So really the opposite of "append" might be something like "appose" or "adhere". "Prepend", notwithstanding its documented use, seems coined from a complete misunderstanding.

Comment: +1 "Prepend" seems coined from a complete misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/prepend there is no such thing as "to prepend"

> The correct English word is "prefix;" for example, "the header is prefixed to the packet." See prefix.

and

> prefix:
>   The beginning or to add to the beginning

Comment: True - but this doesn't answer the question that you asked!

Comment: @Steve it does! the answer is "prefix"

Comment: "Prefix" is the opposite of "suffix". The opposite of "appendix" is less obvious, but ptomato's suggestions are closer (in my opinion).

Comment: *OED* says "prepend, *v.* To add at the beginning, to prefix, prepose" with earliest citation from 1872.

Comment: @Gareth and there is 7,680 Google results for `prependix`

Comment: cp *affix*, which subsumes prefix and suffix. Also note that *preposition* often appears right-hand side.